# Entering the UK as a tourist after recently visiting as a student visitor?

Tags: visas, uk, canadian-citizens

I went on a three and a half month exchange to the UK Sept 2014 to DEc 2014. I've been back here at home in Canada since and now, in May 2015, will be going back to visit my boyfriend as a tourist for three months.

What documents should I bring along? Should I expect to be questioned?

I already plan to bring bank statements, proof of funds, a letter from my boyfriend stating I will be staying with him while I'm there, and proof of my return trip.

Comment: Yes, I'm a Canadian citizen.

Comment: I'm not so much looking if I need a visa, more concerned with whether or not they'll find it strange that I'm visiting so long so soon after studying abroad.

Comment: @Melissa, yes, you can expect more scrutiny when you arrive. "on paper" you are ok, but there's a suggestion that you are also building up a private life in the UK.

Comment: They should still let me enter though, right?

Answer (score 1):

As a Canadian citizen you [don't need a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/canada/tourism) to come to the UK, however, the same site recommends you to bring the same documents you would [if you apply for a visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/343241/2014_08_Visitor_Documents.pdf):

- Letter of employment (if you have one)
- Proof of funds (Bank statements, tax returns)

As far as being questioned this is actually at the discretion of the border control officers so the best answer is: depends on quite a fiew things.